# Pytorch: correct way to sum batch loss with epoch loss

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I'm calculating two losses. One per batch and one per epoch, at the end of the batches loop. When I try to sum these two losses I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by   an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [64, 49]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

I have my reasons for summing these two losses.

The general idea of the code is something like this:

```
loss_epoch = 0 # it's zero in the first epoch

for epoch in epochs:
    for batch in batches:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
        loss_batch = criterion_batch(output_batch, target_batch)
        loss = loss_batch + loss_epoch # adds zero in the first epoch
    
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
    loss_epoch = criterion_epoch(output_epoch, target_epoch)
```

I get that the problem is I'm modifying the gradient when I calculate another loss at the end of the first loop (the loop that goes through the batches) but I couldn't solve this problem.
It also might have something to do with the order of the operations (loss calculation, backward, zero_grad, step).
I need to calculate the `loss_epoch` at the end of the batch loop because I'm using the entire dataset to calculate this loss.

Comment: I'm not sure of your use case so its hard to say if what you're doing makes sense. Without that information, the most I can suggest, implement a custom loss function that takes the batch index and batch total. When the current batch index equals the total, calculate and add the epoch loss into the returned loss value. Then you don't need to calculate a separate loss in the outer loop.

Comment: Assuming that you do not want to backpropagate the `epoch_loss` through every forward pass for the entire dataset (which of course would be computationally infeasible for a dataset of any non-trivial size), you could detach the `epoch_loss` and essentially add it as a scalar which is updated once per epoch. Not entirely sure if this is the behavior you want though.

Comment: @DerekG this solved my problem. I didn't think it would be that simple. Previously I was trying to clone the parameters (one of the possible fixes I found). Thank you.

Comment: @jaryl great! I wrote it up as a small answer. If you wouldn't mind can you accept that answer so that SO algorithms can consider this problem solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you do not want to backpropagate the `epoch_loss` through every forward pass for the entire dataset (which of course would be computationally infeasible for a dataset of any non-trivial size), you could detach the epoch_loss and essentially add it as a scalar which is updated once per epoch. Not entirely sure if this is the behavior you want though.